# Open link in parent's iframe / more specific "_parent"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm working on an page-concept with multiple iframes.
You can use target="_parent" to open a link whithin an iframe in it's parent.

But how can I spicify where exactly in this parent-window the link should be opend?

Lets say you have something like:

```
<div id="parent">
    <iframe name="target_a">
        <a href="something.html" target="???">Test</a>
    </iframe>

    <iframe name="target_b"></iframe>
</div>
```

So how do I make the link to find "_parent target_b"?

Comment: `window.parent.target_b`?

Comment: That should be `target="target_b"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iframe`s `name` as a target:

```
<div id="parent">
    <iframe name="target_a">
        <a href="something.html" target="target_b">Test</a>
    </iframe>

    <iframe name="target_b"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds too easy^^ I mean, isn't the link trying to find "target_b" in "something.html" that way? But it needs to go up to "index.html"/parent and then find "target_b".  Heavn't tried it yet. I guess I'll have the time on monday to check it.